# Order array by value and put at the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, numbers

Very quick question,
I want to order an array by specific value and put it always at the middle.
For example... if my array is:

```
myarr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

the function middlelizeArr(myarr,2) should me returns this array:

```
 result [5,1,2,3,4]
```

and find the best condition in case of even array

```
    myarr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

result [7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

How could I do this? Someone can help me?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: 1) You need to show us what you have attempted before asking for help. 2) Don't even think of the code. Imagine you've got a bunch of buckets with pieces of paper with a number written on each. How would **you** sort that? Try that process out with a few different numbers then you've got your algorithm. Translate that to code and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to have a size of an array and find the location of a number you want to put into the middle

If, 
 n = size of an array
 l = location of the number you want to put it into the middle

if n/2 > l, then shift your number clockwise otherwise shift it anti clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by comparing the index of the "middle" number to the length of the array, and then shifting (and pushing) until they're equal.

I've implemented it the following way:

```
function middlelizeArray(array, middle) {
    var goal = Math.trunc(array.length/2);

    while(array.indexOf(middle) != goal) {
        array.push(array.shift());
    }
    return array;
}
```

This could also be added directly to the array prototype. This would allow you to just say `myArray.middlelize(2);`

That would be done like so:

```
Array.prototype.middlelize = function(middle) {
    var goal = Math.trunc(this.length/2);
    while(this.indexOf(middle) != goal) {
        this.push(this.shift());
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: and if I want to make the same thing with a Obj?
for example... i want to order a list UL by specific value of li... so my structure is...
<ul>
<li value="1">1</li>
<li value="2">2</li>
<li value="3">3</li>
<li value="4">4</li>
<li value="5">5</li>
<li value="6">6</li>
</ul>

How can I order this this?

This doesn't work
$('ul').find('li').middlelize(7);